# Php mailer script not working with google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, recaptcha

I have a little problem implementing google recaptchas to my PHP mailer program.

## PROBLEM

So Here is my problem, When i click submit on my contact form. I get a 403 error, which is called by the last else in the PHP. This is called when the above code isn't working. So the problem is somewhere from the beginning of the PHP file, to right before the last else statement. And i cant find anything wrong with it. Also, im not so fluent in PHP.

Here is my HTML

## HTML

```
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="../../mailer.php">
    <h1>We Look Forward To Speaking With You!</h1>
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>

    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

    <input id="tel" name="tel" type="tel" placeholder="Phone" required>

    <input id="time" name="time" type="text" placeholder="Prefered Time: Morning, Noon, Afternoon, Evening">

    <input id="method" name="method" type="text" placeholder="Prefered Method of Contact: Phone, Email, Text, Other">

    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Send us a message!" required></textarea>
    <div class="recaptcha-box">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdJgSUTAAAAAI6IJfPhaHh7aMWjVPsL4_B9OHGj"></div>
    </div>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

here is my JS

## JAVASCRIPT

```
function sendEmail() {
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
    var formData = $(form).serialize();


    $(form).submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data: formData
    })

    .done(function(response) {
      $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
      $(formMessages).addClass('success');

      $(formMessages).text(response);
      $('#name').val('');
      $('#email').val('');
      $('#tel').val('');
      $('#time').val('');
      $('#method').val('');
      $('#message').val('');
      location.assign("http://www.theppcgroup.com/thank-you.html");
    })

    .fail(function(data) {
      $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
      $(formMessages).addClass('error');

      if (data.responseText !== '') {
          $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
      } else {
          $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
      }
    });
  }

if ($('#submit').on('click', function() {
  sendEmail();
}));
```

here is my PHP

## PHP

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['sumbit'])) {
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = 'Cant give you key, Sorry :)';

    $response = file_get_contents($url.'?secret='.$privatekey."$response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($response);

    if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {

        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $phone = trim($_POST["tel"]);
        $time = trim($_POST["time"]);
        $method = trim($_POST["method"]);
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "WebInquiry@ThePPCGroup.Com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";
        $msg = "Thank you for contacting ThePPCGroup.\nSomeone will contact you shortly. Please let us know the best time to reach you, and if phone or email is better.\nThePPCGroup\n855-539-4742\nWebInquiry@ThePPCGroup.Com\nWWW.ThePPCGroup.Com";
        $headers = 'From: WebInquiry@ThePPCGroup.Com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: WebInquiry@ThePPCGroup.Com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Prefered Time: $time\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Prefered Method: $method\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            mail($email, "Thank You!", $msg, $headers);
        }
      }
        else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: It looks to me it is called when the `if (isset($_POST['sumbit']))` conditional fails

Comment: Yes, There was a typo that was making that fail. @oli

Answer (score 0):

it is failing because there are misspelled character.

Change

```
if (isset($_POST['sumbit']))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

apart from this do check `$('#form-messages');`id name in javascript. there is a mismatch with PHP id (textarea).

hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Didn't fix it, and what do you mean a miss match?

Comment: in HTML your textarea id name is id="message" & in javascript $('#form-messages');

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo

```
$response = file_get_contents($url.'?secret='.$privatekey."$response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

needed to be

```
$response = file_get_contents($url.'?secret='.$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

There was a $ instead of a &